# How to Model and ViewModel implementation for simple database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oop

I am trying my first steps with Microsoft ASP.Net MVC. I set up a simple database for being able to test all facets like Controllers, Views, Model, ViewModel, etc.

The case behind is to have simple Projects and Resources. Each Project can have multiple Resources. Each assigned Resource to a Project can have a Role (string).

My database model looks like this:

```
Projects
    Id <int>
    Name <string>
    CreatedAt <datetime>
    CreatedBy <string>

Resource
    Id <int>
    Name <string>
    CreatedAt <datetime>
    CreatedBy <string>

ProjectResources
    Id <int>
    ProjectId <int>
    ResourceId <int> 
    Role <string>
    CreatedAt <datetime>
    CreatedBy <string>
```

The first thing is to build the EntityClasses within the solution. I could have it like this:

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string  Name { get; set; }
    // IS THIS CORRECT? WHERE DO I HAVE TO PUT THE ROLE?
    public List<Resource> Resources { get; set; }
    public string  CreatedBy { get; }
    public datetime  CreatedAt { get; }
}

public class Resource
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string  Name { get; set; }
    public string  CreatedBy { get; }
    public datetime  CreatedAt { get; }
}
```

This is the first part of the question. The second part is on ViewModels. What i have read is, that ViewModels should only contain those information which are rendered on a view. When i have 3 different views for 2 different purposes for example:

- Get list of projects
- Get single Project with assigned resources
- Save (edit/update & create new) project with assigned resources

So the question is: How could the ViewModel(s) look like? Do i need to have multiple ViewModels (from my understanding yes)? I have thought about it but dont know if this is ok (is there also any NamingConvention for ViewModels):

```
    public class ListOfProjectsViewModel
    {
        List<Project> projects { get; set; }
    }
```

But in this case where and how to put the joined Resources?

```
public class ProjectDetailViewModel
{
    Project project { get; set; }
    List<Resource> resources { get; set; }
}
```

In the class ProjectDetailViewModel i would have the list of resources for the dropdown but where to put the added/selected resources per project and the selected resources role?

Comment: VIew models should not contain properties which are data models - [What is ViewModel in MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)

Comment: @Stephen thats correct. I know this and therefore the intention is to have the classic models which are a representation of the database model/business objects and the viewmodels which only contain information for rendering those information on the view. My question is not what the viewmodel should contain instead i want to know how to handle joined resources for example.

Comment: There is no ViewModel in MVC (Model, View, Controller) so I am not sure why people assume the thing which is passed to the view is ViewModel. It is  a model.

Comment: @CodingYoshi - So its distinguishable between a data model and a view model :)

Comment: A view has a property called Model, so whatever you pass to it is a model. A ViewModel will kick into play if using KnockoutJs on the browser side. ViewModels should be interactive and declarative and have methods, handlers, binding etc. But yes, I get what you mean and a lot of people think of them like that but nonetheless it is not correct.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by joined resources. Both your 'view models' in the question contain data models which is not correct. Your `ProjectDetailVM` might contain a property `string Name` and if your also wanting to edit a collection of Resource` in the same view, it might contain a property `List<ResourceVM> Resources` where `ResourceVM` contains a property `string Name`

Comment: @CodingYoshi: This might be in general correct but the "ViewModel" contains from my understanding more then maybe one table or not all of the properties of a class and should contain only things which are needed to get rendered within the view. And therefore for me they are no classic Models instead ViewModels :) And again, of course they are models but from my perspective not the same to my model which is a representation of my database model. But to not move the question/answer or comments into a wrong direction: my question is how to can i design the models as already asked in my question?

Comment: @Stephen: With joined resources i mean that one project can have multiple project members (resources). Those resources are reprensented in the database by a dedicated table for the projects, a table for the resources and a separate intermediate table for joining n resources to m projects with a role description inside the intermediate table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a project can have multiple resources, then `Project` will have a navigation property of a list of `Resource` and `Resource` will have a navigation property of a single `Project`. Of course this is making the assumption that one resource can be on a single project. Otherwise it will be a many to many relationship and you will have a `List<T>` navigation property on both sides.

Now the role: depending on your needs if a `Resource` can have multiple roles and role obviously has multiple resources, then again it is many to many so `List<T>` on both sides.

Also, you will need simple properties for (foreign keys) so they can be enforced by the database. Also, there will be cases when you just load a `Resource` without loading its `Role` (navigation property) and thus you need the `RoleId`.

As for the ViewModels:

Like I said, and I do not want to start this debate, there is no ViewModel in MVC. This is why the View has Model property. So whatever you pass to it is the Model. This is why there is a model folder.

Name your views as per operations such as Edit, Create, List (will display a list of x items) etc. Your `Resource` will need the following structure:

Views:

Resource
   - Edit
   - Create
   - List

Models:

Resource
    - EditModel or (ResourceEditModel)
    - CreateModel
    - ListModel

Your ListModel may have properties such as `Total`, `PageNumber` and your `EditModel` may have a list of `Project` for a dropdown selection and other items. That is all pretty normal. So you have the models for your views and then you have the models for your database and you may even have domain models.

And obviously you will have the controllers. Once you start using binding, error handling and validation on the client side, you will need ViewModels but at that point you are in the MVVM playground.